# Loading Tile Source

Tags: android, openstreetmap, tile, osmdroid

I'm trying to load a tile source, but for some reason it doenst work.
Here's my code:

```
    final IRegisterReceiver registerReceiver = new SimpleRegisterReceiver(this);

    // Create a custom tile source
    final ITileSource tileSource = TileSourceFactory.MAPNIK;

    // Create a file cache modular provider
    final TileWriter tileWriter = new TileWriter();
    final MapTileFilesystemProvider fileSystemProvider = new MapTileFilesystemProvider(registerReceiver, tileSource);

    File myMapTileSource = new File(mapsDirectory.getPath()+File.separator+"Lisboa.gemf");

    // Create an archive file modular tile provider
    IArchiveFile[] archives = { ArchiveFileFactory.getArchiveFile(myMapTileSource) };
    MapTileFileArchiveProvider fileArchiveProvider = new MapTileFileArchiveProvider(registerReceiver, tileSource, archives);

    // Create a download modular tile provider
    final NetworkAvailabliltyCheck networkAvailablilityCheck = new NetworkAvailabliltyCheck(this);
    final MapTileDownloader downloaderProvider = new MapTileDownloader(tileSource, tileWriter, networkAvailablilityCheck);

    // Create a custom tile provider array with the custom tile source and the custom tile providers
    final MapTileProviderArray tileProviderArray = new MapTileProviderArray(tileSource, registerReceiver, new MapTileModuleProviderBase[] { fileSystemProvider, fileArchiveProvider, downloaderProvider });

    // Create the mapview with the custom tile provider array
    mMapView = new MapView(this, 256, new DefaultResourceProxyImpl(this), tileProviderArray);
    mMapView.setUseDataConnection(false);
```

For some reason this works and i can see the map of lisbon offline.

if i switch the line

```
File myMapTileSource = new File(mapsDirectory.getPath()+File.separator+"Lisboa.gemf");
```

for

```
File myMapTileSource = new File(mapsDirectory.getPath()+File.separator+"Lissabon.osm");
```

it doenst work. It returns an error "Error loading tile" from MapTileFileArchiveProvider.

The gemf file was created in MOBAC. The osm file was downloaded from [here](http://download.bbbike.org/osm/bbbike/Lissabon/).

Could anyone explain me why it doenst work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at [ArchiveFileFactory](https://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/source/browse/trunk/osmdroid-android/src/main/java/org/osmdroid/tileprovider/modules/ArchiveFileFactory.java), you'll see that GEMF files are supported, but .osm files are not. I'm not sure what format .osm files are (maybe it's one of the supported formats and just needs to be renamed?)

Comment: you'r correct. I thought that gemf files were a tile source. i probably had a bad interpretation from what i read. osm is a meta data format xml file. [source](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSM_XML)
So if i want to load a custom map using osmdroid i'll have to get the tile source from a "zip", "sqlite", "mbtiles" or "gemf" right?
which one would you suggest?

Comment: I believe I have heard of speed issues with zip files when they get large so I would avoid that. I have had good results with gemf. Mbtiles uses sqlite at its core and I hear good things about that too!

Comment: is it possible to create an mbtile in MOBAC?

Comment: Sorry - I don't have any experience with MOBAC.