# Using hand drawn map in android application

Tags: android, image, dictionary, gps

In my android application I want to use "handmade" maps. It's an artistic map image, based on a real map, so it's geographically accurate. The map cover a relatively small, walkable area (like a neighborhood in a city). The map is bigger than the screen size, so the user will drag the map (but always at the same scale, so no zooming). The application has to work offline, with no Internet connection, but I want to show the user's current (possibly moving) GPS position on this map. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Learn how to get GPS location, and how to map it to pixels on your handdrawn image.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible, and in your case not so difficult.
Measure 3 reference point;
1. near or at left upper corner (NW)
2. near or at right upper corner (NE)
3. near or lef middle or right lower corner (S).

next step is to map the 3 points to pixel and screen coordinates.  
Then you need to do an linear interpolation for latitude (between y/lat coordinate of Point 1 and 3)
And an separate linear interpolation between Point1 and 2 for longitude /x value of your GPS coordinate.

With this knowledge, you search further and read some poste here, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into [OpenStreetMap](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Android) for your mapping.  It allows you to specify a custom tile source for the map.  Here is a [related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19634260/loading-tile-source).
You will need to break your image up into pieces, [this site](https://www.mapbox.com/help/how-web-maps-work/) gives a good explanation on how the tiles are formatted.